# Limit the number of products shown in mini cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am using WooCommerce mini cart widget and I want to limit the number of products shown in the mini cart. If a user adds 10 products to the cart, the mini cart widget shows all 10.

I would like to limit the number lets say to **5 products**.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this overriding **`cart/mini-cart.php`** WooCommerce template via your active theme, *( see this related docs: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) )*.

Briefly (if not done yet), you will need to copy from **`woocommerce`** plugin folder, a subfolder named **`templates`** to your active child theme (or theme) and to rename it **`woocommerce`**..

After that you find inside that new **`woocommerce`** folder in **`cart`** subfolder a template named **`mini-cart.php`**.

Open/edit **`mini-cart.php`** template and replace the code by this to limit cart to 5 items:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mini-cart
 *
 * Contains the markup for the mini-cart, used by the cart widget.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<ul class="cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo $args['list_class']; ?>">

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

        <?php
            // Define HERE the number of items
            $number_of_items = 5;
            $loop_count = 0;

            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                // Limiting number of items displayed in mini cart
                if($loop_count < $number_of_items) {
                    // The counter
                    $loop_count++;
                    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                        $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                            <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                            <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?>
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <li class="empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></li>

    <?php endif; ?>

</ul><!-- end product list -->

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

    <p class="total"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

    <p class="buttons">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="button wc-forward"><?php _e( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="button checkout wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
    </p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Here we count the number of items in the foreach loop and we limit them to a specified number in variable **`$number_of_items`**.